# Word for "the action of making something optimistic"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phrase-requests

Is there such a word or concise paraphrase that corresponds? *Optimize* might have the same root but it obviously doesn't have the same meaning. Is there any verbal form that could fit or does *optimism* (and any other philosophy) imply a self state?

Comment: How about an example or more context?

Comment: I think this is Not A Real Question. You can't make a **thing** "optimistic" - optimism is an attitude of mind, not an attribute you can bestow on inanimate objects.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is part of the question.

Comment: @coleopterist "By cutting out all the articles that pleased him the  man made the world (seem) more optimistic".

Comment: @James Poulson: That's a devious example which doesn't specifically relate to the word "optimistic" (you could substitute "cheerful", for example). It doesn't mean *the world itself* became more cheerful/optimistic - it means *the old man* did (when he thought about the world, if you want to drag that noun in).

Comment: I can only suggest something along the lines of: "_By cutting out all the articles that pleased him, the man brightened his world". _vivified_, _enlivened_, _vitalised_, etc. could also be good fits. But I don't believe that they answer your requirements exactly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comments answer the question :) . So this is to be considered as a misuse of the language. I will use one of the alternatives given.

Comment: The only phrase I can think of would be along the lines of "*she put on rose-colored glasses*".

Comment: That is a possibility. To go along with what @FumbleFingers is saying the actual effect of the glasses takes place in the self.

Comment: @Zairja That's an excellent suggestion. Incidentally, I've only ever heard it used as "rose-*tinted* glasses". Odd.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point and good riposte. How do you feel about things being _scary_? I was looking for a word meaning 'take away the frightening nature of' a few years ago, and realised that _things_ really aren't inherently frightening. This was prompted when a person on a computer-literacy course said they were attending just to 'de-scarify' the whole scene.

Comment: Perhaps pedantic, but we do talk about computer algorithms being "optimistic".

Comment: In the absence of more context, I'd interpret the sentence about how the man "made the world optimistic" to mean that he made people in general more optimistic, i.e. he made all the people of the world optimistic, as opposed to he made himself more optimistic about the world.

Comment: Here is one possible context. http://leagueofpragmaticoptimists.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [*inspire*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inspire):

> To infuse into; to affect, as with a superior or supernatural influence; to fill with what animates, enlivens or exalts; to communicate inspiration to

Similarly, there is *embolden*, *galvanize*, *kindle* and so on.

As far as "conferring" one possibility includes [*sublimate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sublimate) ((archaic) to raise to a place of honor). You might also *indoctrinate* someone in a school of thought or *impart* your worldviews.

If you want a phrase, perhaps simply "she *turned* optimistic" would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious is *[whitewash](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whitewash#Verb)*, “to cover over errors or bad actions”.  Verb *[calcimine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calcimine#Verb)* is a near-synonym for that, well-known but not commonly used.  Less seriously, consider *[gloss over](http://www.onelook.com/?loc=rescb&refclue=whitewash&w=gloss+over)*, *[rosetint](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rosetinted)* and *[pangloss](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Panglossian)*.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any instances of *calcimine* used in this metaphorical sense?

Comment: @Zairja, I looked at length and didn't find any, but I'm sure they're out there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still wondering what the something is that you're trying to make optimistic, but it seems that the common paraphrases are to *inspire optimism* or *bring hope (to)* or *make optimal*, depending on what you mean by 'something'.